# What is this error and why cant i start npm?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I iried to start npm using npm start, bu all i see is
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-59-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5

npm ERR! missing script: start
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/npm-debug.log

Comment: did you find solution?